# Rotating One Object Around Another In createJS/easelJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, createjs, easeljs

In easelJS, what is the best way to rotate an object around another? What I'm trying to accomplish is a method to rotate the crosshair around the circle pictured below, just like a planet orbits the sun:

[image]

I've been able to rotate objects around their own center point, but am having a difficult time devising a way to rotate one object around the center point of a second object. Any ideas?

Comment: can't you just move your crosshair on a circle trajectory using circle's parametric equation ?

Comment: @ampawd thanks for this suggestion, that parametric equation was exactly what I needed. However, when I begin the rotation with an angle of 1 degree in the equation my point first moves to a point directly to the right of the origin around which it is rotating. To move a point from an arbitrary starting point, however, am I correct in thinking I would first need to determine the angle formed by the origin, that point to the right, and my arbitrary point? Would the law of cosines be the way to go about that? I can provide an illustration of my question if this isn't a clear enough explanation.

Comment: if you know crosshair's coordinates, just move it on circle trajectory using this formula: `x = distance * Math.cos(angle) + cricle.center.x, y = distance*Math.sin(angle) + circle.center.y` where `distance` is a distance between crosshair and circle

Comment: @ampawd the problem was that I didn't know the angle value, but I solved it using the law of cosines like I mentioned above. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Might make sense to wrap content in a Container. Translate the coordinates so the center point is where you want it, and then rotate the container.

Comment: when you say translate the coordinates do you mean set the center point as the center of the container? This is a great idea though, I'll see if I can work it out. You've been a great resource for all my easelJS questions, thanks man!

Comment: Yeah, like if you want the center point to be at 100x100, you can easily put your contents in a container, set the container regX/regY to that point, and then offset your content by 100x100 so its visibly in the same place. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

To build on what Lanny is suggesting, there may be cases where you don't want to rotate the entire container. An alternative would be to use trigonometric functions and an incrementing angle to calculate the x/y position of the crosshair. You can find the x/y by using an angle (converted to radians) and `Math.cos(angleInRadians)` for x and `Math.sin(angleInRadians)` for y, the multiply by the radius of the orbit.

See this [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/4nL937tm/) for reference.

Here's a complete snippet.

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("stage");
var angle = 0;

var circle = new createjs.Shape();
circle.graphics.beginFill("#FF0000").drawEllipse(-25, -25, 50, 50).endFill();
circle.x = 100;
circle.y = 100;

var crosshair = new createjs.Shape();
crosshair.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2).beginStroke("#FF0000").moveTo(5, 0).lineTo(5, 10).moveTo(0, 5).lineTo(10, 5).endStroke();

stage.addChild(circle);
stage.addChild(crosshair);

createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", function(){

  angle++;
  if(angle > 360)
    angle = 1;

    var rads = angle * Math.PI / 180;
    var x = 100 * Math.cos(rads);
    var y = 100 * Math.sin(rads);
    crosshair.x = x + 100;
    crosshair.y = y + 100;

    stage.update();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put another point respect to origin point with the same direction

```js
var one_meter = 1 / map_resolution;

// get one meter distance from pointed points
var extra_x = one_meter * Math.cos(temp_rotation);
var extra_y = one_meter * Math.sin(-temp_rotation);

var new_x = mapXY.x + extra_x;
var new_y = mapXY.y + extra_y;

var home_point = new createjs.Shape().set({ x: new_x, y: new_y });
home_point.graphics.beginFill("Blue").drawCircle(0, 0, 10);

stage.addChild(home_point);
stage.update();
```

[image]

[image]